# Make youself.... phrases in context

Tags: phrase-usage

Please, tell me how I should use these phrases:

- "make yourself at ease"
- "make yourself comfortable"
- "make yourself at home"

Answer (score 1):

“Make yourself at ease” is not idiomatic or something I recall ever having heard said or seen written. When I google it what comes up is a lot of references to foreign languages.

Much more common is to be “put”, not “made”, at ease, though you wouldn’t typically direct someone to “put yourself at ease”, one would more be put at ease by something.

The closest thing I’ve heard to “put yourself at ease” the army command “at ease”.

Your other two phrases are very idiomatic and basically mean what they say, and also imply a degree of authority (to sort of tell people how they may behave in a particular environment).

I suppose the difference would be that you would usually ask someone to make themselves “at home” if you were in a place where you also felt at home. If you visit a doctor, they may say “make yourself comfortable,” but it would sound quite odd for them to say “make yourself at home.”

Answer (score 0):

Though all three might be used to greet someone in your environment and to put them at ease, the first simply lets the person know she or he is *not* in trouble and can relax.

The other two also imply, just a bit, that the person being addresses should feel comfortable in the facilities, e.g., adjusting a chair, or possibly taking some food that has been set out for them (perhaps with a nonverbal indications, such as pointing).